# Gazebo crashing when subscribing to /scan

Tags: c++, ros

I am running ros kinetic in Ubuntu 16.04 on Oracle VM Virtual Box.

I am launching gazebo with:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

I then try to echo the /scan topic with: (I have checked that it's being published):

```
rostopic echo /scan
```

It outputs:

```
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?
```

/clock is indeed being published.

And then gazebo crashes with the following:

> gzserver: /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreRenderSystem.cpp:546: virtual void Ogre::RenderSystem::setDepthBufferFor(Ogre::RenderTarget*): Assertion `bAttached && "A new DepthBuffer for a RenderTarget was created, but after creation" "it says it's incompatible with that RT"' failed.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)
>
> [gazebo-2] process has died [pid 8979, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/joshua/.ros/log/409e3080-4711-11e9-abe9-0800270fc685/gazebo-2.log].
>   log file: /home/joshua/.ros/log/409e3080-4711-11e9-abe9-0800270fc685/gazebo-2*.log

I have tried setting my VM to accelerate 3D graphics, create my own rosnode that subscribes to /scan and look at help threads I can find yet I still cannot solve this issue. Any assistance would be great.

**Additional note:**
I can `rostopic echo /clock` perfectly fine, and control the turtlebot with teleop perfectly fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue I was required to update gazebo:

Step 1:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'
```

Step 2:

```
wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Step 3:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 4:

```
sudo apt-get install gazebo7
```

Accessing the /scan topic with `rostopic echo /scan` now works as intended.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, Kinetic on 16.04 running natively on a Lenovo Yoga Ryzen-7 laptop.